# Keep div2 flush with left, bottom, and right of screen, but always 400px below above div1?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one on top (div1) and one on bottom (div2).

What I'm looking to accomplish: div2 should always be 400px below div1, but... I want div2's left, bottom, and right sides to always be flush w/ the browser window. No matter the size of the screen, those 3 sides should always be flush. How can I do this?

What I've tried so far:

```
.background-oval {
    background-color: #999;
    border-top-left-radius: 100%100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%100px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried? Also please provide a little more context. Is there going to be content between _div1_ and _div2_? Also, please clarify one thing, when you mention _"div1's left, bottom and right sides to always be flush w/ the browser window," did you mean _div2_?

Comment: Added code. Therewill be content between the two divs.

Comment: So, if div1 is 600px height and div2 is 300, and you don't have a 1300px height monitor, theb what should happen? Wich rules should be broken first?

Comment: "Flush" is aligned to those edges of the browser window.

Comment: @Balint: They should always be 400px apart, even when the browser window shrinks, and then you'd be able to scroll

Comment: then how can the bottom border of the top div be aligned to the border of the browser window? (that's what you basically wrote)

Comment: Crap, misworded it, reread again, just edited it. div2 will always have left, bottom, and right flush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

document.body.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    div2.style.top = Math.max(
        - -(div2.style.top.slice(0, -2)) + div2.height + 400,
        document.body.scrollTop + innerHeight - div2.height
    ) + "px";
}
```

Note: `- -` is a way to convert a string into a number

Note2: This assumes, that div2 has a position attribute  and a height